# Change SPF records of multiple domain names in WHM

Tags: cpanel, whm, exim

I recently changed the IP address of Exim that email sending uses a different IP address from the main shared IP of WHM.

Now I realized that I need to change the SPF value 100's of domains from WHM

From

`"v=spf1 +a +mx +ip4:xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx ~all"`

to

`"v=spf1 +a +mx +ip4:xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx +ip4:xxx.xxx.xxx.yyy ~all"`

Is there a fast way to do this aside from manually editing each domain?

Answer (score 0):

You can change all domain zone through command line using **replace** command

Please check it : http://www.computerhope.com/unix/replace.htm

Answer (score 0):

WHM v. 78 has new feature that allows adding new hosts for all domains in the WHM system.
On the [WHM 78 release notes page](https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/78Docs/78+Release+Notes), search for "New settings for smarthost route lists" to learn how to do it.

Also even in older WHM version one can use [SPF installer script](https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/80Docs/The+spf_installer+Script). Currently the example command to make sure some domain has additional values 1.2.3.4 and host.name.tld is:

```
/usr/local/cpanel/bin/spf_installer cpanelusername '+ip4:1.2.3.4,+include:host.name.tld' 0 1 0
```

Note the + signs and comma between the two values. The command will make sure the SPF has these two values beside the server IP value that is added by WHM by default.

To apply on all users, i did:

```
for user in $(ls -A1 /var/cpanel/users/ | grep -Ev "system|\."); do /usr/local/cpanel/bin/spf_installer "$user" '+ip4:1.2.3.4,+include:host.name.tld' 0 1 0;done
```

to check the result, do command

```
dig txt hosteddomain.com
```

(if the domain is behind proxy like cloudflare, the result will not be visible immediately)